# Check for repetitions in a list and update it if so

Tags: python, list

We have a list, for instance one of the following:

```py
lista = ['facility', 'resource', 'resource', 'resource', 'facility', 'other', 'resource', 'resource']
listb = ['facility', 'resource', 'other', 'another']
```

And we need a function that returns the following:

```py
lista_new = ['facility', 'resource', 'resource1', 'resource2', 'facility1', 'other', 'resource3', 'resource4']
listb_new = ['facility', 'resource', 'other', 'another']
```

It would be great to do it without using Numpy, and it would be even better to obtain:

```py
lista_new = ['facility0', 'resource0', 'resource1', 'resource2', 'facility1', 'other', 'resource3', 'resource4']
listb_new = ['facility', 'resource', 'other', 'another']
```

My possible solution is posted as a possible answer.

Comment: Why downvoting? xd

Comment: @KellyBundy to see that if the element is unique, we don't need to update it with a '0' in the name. To indicate that this behavior is not because of the item name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) works just fine for this.

```py
lista = ['facility', 'resource', 'resource', 'resource', 'facility',
         'other', 'resource', 'resource']
uniques = {label for label, count
           in collections.Counter(lista).items() if count == 1}
counter = collections.Counter()
def get_add(label):
    counter[label] += 1
    return counter[label] - 1
new_lista = [label if label in uniques else f"{label}{get_add(label)}"
             for label in lista]
```

Comment: This updates 'other' as 'other0', but it shouldn't be updated

Comment: @geofisue good catch. That exception is not obvious. Wonder if it is even intentional

Comment: but this is because 'other' was unique in the list, not because its name

Comment: @geofisue clarifying your requirements up-front generally leads to better answers. Just saying

Comment: It is clarified, you just need to pass to your previous code the second list I put as an example in my original post, and you will see your code is not doing what i asked. But thanks for trying!

Answer (score 2):

Make a function that would iterate over input list and count each item using count. If count = 1 (first encounter) keep it. But if count>1 for any item , delete it.

```
def duplli_checker(lst):
    count = {}
    new_lst = []
    for item in lst:
        if item not in count:
            count[item] = 0
            new_lst.append(item)
        else:
            count[item] += 1
            new_lst.append(f"{item}{count[item]}")
    return new_lst
```

Try inputing your answer

```
lista = ['facility', 'resource', 'resource', 'resource', 'facility', 'other', 'resource', 'resource']
listb = ['facility', 'resource', 'other', 'another']

lista_new = duplli_checker(lsta)
listb_new = duplli_checker(lstb)

print(lista_new)
print(listb_new)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There are two good answers, but I just can select one

Answer (score 0):

*This solution uses Numpy and doesn't put a 0 in updated names.*

We use a `seen` set where we add the first time seen items. We use a `varios` list where we append the items that we have seen already. Updated list is stored in `new`. The updated item name is computed as `item + str(number)` where `number` is the number of times the current item is present in `varios`, `sum(np.array(varios) == item)`. There is also a `flag` to account for changes.

```py
import numpy as np

def checkRepetition(lista):
    flag = 0
    seen = set()
    varios = []
    new = []
    for item in lista:
        if item in seen:
            varios.append(item)
            number = sum(np.array(varios) == item)
            new.append(item + str(number))
        else:
            seen.add(item)
            new.append(item)
    if len(varios) > 0:
        flag = 1
    if flag:
        return new
    else:
        return lista
```